Geometry Nodes - How can I array beams on this bendy plane?
Got beams arranged along a curve with a simple geo node setup

but that's not what I want.
Here’s the curve expanded into a plane with curving edges:

So now how do I arrange the beams to fit that curved plane and stretch out to the edges like this: 
doing it with booleans will just ends up like this (which I don’t want): 

How is the curve expanded into a plane with curving edges? By scaling the control points? Then why not sample the point radius and use it for the width of the beams?

@GordonBrinkmann I convert it to mesh, solidify it, then trim the edges from there. I need the beams to array procedurally

With this geo nodes set-up, you can use the radius property of each control point.


Just use the Spline Parameter > Factor which is a 0 to 1 range from curve start to end as a scaling factor for the Y axis of instanced cubes. Use a Float Curve to adjust the width to your liking.


Existing answers are correct, but keep in mind nothing stops you from using boolean, just use manifold-but very thin lines, to then merge them and convert them to curves and give them a profile of your choice:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
